# How to change primary color for Prime NG

Tags: css, angular, primeng

How can I change default primary color for primeNG (saga-blue theme) ? changing --primary-color doesn't help, because in node_modules/..../theme.css elements are styled using the main color hex and not ' --primary-color '.
I also can't override styling for all elements that use that primary color because they are too many + they have different shades of --primary-color on hover and on focus, how can I handle this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the primary color to green, orange, or purple, you can change your theme to one of those (saga-green, saga-orange...)

If you want more customization, you can use [their theme designer](https://www.primefaces.org/designer/primeng).

Comment: Was looking for a free solution, but ok thanks

Comment: I hear you :-). If you hear of one, I'd love to know about it!

Comment: so far I got nothing, but using a built in theme is totally free right?

Comment: If you use one of the free themes, then it is free

Answer (score 7):

I used part of [Ε Г И І И О](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687190/%ce%95-%d0%93-%d0%98-%d0%86-%d0%98-%d0%9e) solution, not sure if it could break something in future yet it's working fine.

My solution:

1. (same) Make a copy of the base theme.css from primeng (Find it from `node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/{your_theme}/theme.css`)
2. (same) Change all colors, etc as per your liking. (Hint: use find -> replace)
3. Save changed `themes.css` to any folder, like `src/app/styles/theme.css` (Hint: you can upgrade to scss and use [color variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) for reuseable and more readable code)
4. Inside `angular.json` under `"styles"` array replace imported `node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/{your_theme}/theme.css` to your path, like `src/app/styles/theme.css`
5. Enjoy, no cpx or node-modules hand changes required, so you can faster move code on another computer!

Comment: Wow that's much much cleaner! Thanks :) I wonder why I took the trouble replacing the original file. That feels so stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hacky workaround.

1. Make a copy of the base theme.css from primeng (Find it from `node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/{your_theme}/theme.css`)
2. Change all colors, etc as per your liking. (Hint: use find -> replace)
3. Save this file in an assets folder. (You can keep it outside of your src folder)
4. Install cpx (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx). It's a file copier.

   `npm install cpx --save-dev`
5. Add the following scripts to your package.json.

   `"copyCss": "cpx \"assets/theme.css\"\"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/{your_theme}/\""`

   `"ngBuild": "npm run copyCss && ng build"`
6. Use `npm run ngBuild` to build your app. (Use any other build switches as desired)
7. Voila! Enjoy your customized styles :)

Answer (score 2):

There is another hard way of doing this,

Like everyone else suggested, copy any theme.css to a file, after that follow below step to convert to scss,
**Step 1** - Using below link, extract all the css colors, not having the part of css variables.
http://www.css-color-extractor.com/

Now, from step-1, we have list of colors to be replaced with css variable

**Step 2** - Use any tool to convert css to SCSS,
for example - https://codebeautify.org/css-to-scss-converter

Copy the **Step -2**, to a new theme.scss file.

-> define a css variable/ scss variable for each colors in step 1,
Do a *find and replace* with all css variable / scss variable for every color found in step-1 (if does not exist).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the SCSS variables (like in the [Prime Theme Designer](https://designer.primeng.org/#/)) and then import the theme SCSS in your **styles.scss** file (for example).

```scss
$primaryColor: red !default;
@import 'node_modules/primeng-sass-theme/themes/nova/nova/theme';
```

To get the theme SCSS, you need to add their [theme repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-sass-theme) as a NPM dependency in your **package.json**.

```json
"dependencies": {
  // ...
  "primeng-sass-theme": "github:primefaces/primeng-sass-theme#16.2.0",
},
```

Answer (score -1):

go to file **style.scss** or **style.css** and change your color need to change it
i need to change **--primarycolor**

```css
:root{
  --primary-color:green;
}
```

Comment: That does not work for the primeng components because these do not use the css variable. Why this is not implement that way I do not know. Would make more sense to me.