# Why are PrimeNG themes css variables not used?

Tags: angular, sass, primeng

I have noticed something strange with tailwind provided themes, If you look at any themes located in `"primeng/resources/themes/*/theme.css"`, you will notice all css variables created in `:root`, but weirdly, they are not used at all.

Taking `mdc-light-indigo` as an example, we have `--primary-color: #0066FF`.

However, I can't find any occurrences of `--primary-color` in this scss, but I found 98 occurrences of `#0066FF`.

I was thinking about importing this theme using `@import "primeng/resources/themes/mdc-light-indigo/theme.css";` to then override those variables, but It can't work that way since all those values are hard-coded.

I have just copied the content of `tailwind-light` into my own theme (instead of importing it with `@import`), and started replacing all occurences of `--primary-color` hex values, with `var(--primary-color)`.

I know this question is similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66199371/how-to-change-primary-color-for-prime-ng), but I would gladely get your input on this.